# What is the difference between $min_x$ and $min$

Tags: optimization, notation, maxima-minima

I have three functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$. I want to know the definition and result of the following minimizations:

1. $\min_x(f(x),g(x),h(x))$ - with $x$ as subscript
2. $\min(f(x),g(x),h(x))$ - without $x$
3. $\min_x\big[\min_x(f(x),g(x),h(x))\big]$
4. $\min\big[\min(f(x),g(x),h(x))\big]$

Update:

5. $\min_{\mathbf{x}}(f(x_1),g(x_2),h(x_3))$

Comment: The subscript of $\min$ is often used to denote the set in which the minimization takes place. For example $\min_{x\in[0,1]}(f(x))$ is the same as $\min(\{f(x):\ x\in[0,1]\})$. In some cases the set is mentioned later, like "$\min_x(f(x))$, for $x\in A$". This is an optimization problem with feasible set $A$ and objective function $f$. In (1) there is a triple $(f(x),g(x),h(x))$ inside the $\min$. One possibility is that that is the beginning of a multi-objective optimization problem. In particular, an incomplete notation. They have yet to say which is the feasible set.

Comment: The first $\min$ in 3. and 4. are absurd.

Comment: @zambawithkolbasa Actually it is not a multi-objective problem. I need to choose one of those functions only. Is it true that the result of the inner-min is a function and then the result of outer-min is constant at the point $x^*$ (optimal solution)?

Comment: @bnbfreak Notation is not unique. You always need to determine what it means from the context. If you are saying that it means to take the minimum of the three functions in some partial order of function, then that is what it is, in your context. I would probably denote that $\min(f,g,h)$. There is another possibility, that it mean the function $m(x)=\min(f(x),g(x),h(x))$.

Comment: @zambawithkolbasa In fact, each function has the different variable, it should be $\min(f(x_1),g(x_2),h(x_3))$. How to write the correct notation to find the minimum of those functions?Let's say $x_1$ makes $f(x_1)$ is lower than $g(x_2)$ and $h(x_3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the (quite unclear) notation :

$\min(f(x),g(x),h(x))$ means that we take the minimum between $f(x), g(x)$ and $h(x)$. Then it is implicitely a function of $x$. The function $x \mapsto \min (f(x),g(x),h(x))$.

$\min_x (f(x),g(x),h(x))$ means that we take the minimum of $\min(f(x),g(x),h(x))
$ for $x$ over a set. It is then a number. A better notation would be :

$$\min_x \min(f(x),g(x),h(x)).$$

To make it (almost) perfect, just specify where $x$ is allowed to vary. For example :

$$\min_{x \in A} \min(f(x),g(x),h(x)).$$

I hope this is enough for 1 and 2.

3 and 4 are not meaningless but the first minimum is irrelevant. Indeed, for 3, you are taking the minimum over a set of a function being constant, then the result is this constant. For 4, it is almost the same, you are taking the minimum of a finite set with only one element.

I may add that you should be carefull with the use of $\min$ in optimization. Indeed, we are talking about minimums only when it can be achieved. It is safer to use $\inf$ unless you know (by assumptions or arguments), that the minimum exists.

Comment: Is it true that $\min_x(f(x),g(x),h(x))$ is equivalent to $\min_x\min(f(x),g(x),h(x))$?

Comment: I would not say equivalent, but understood as. Indeed, how to know if $(f(x),g(x),h(x))$ is greater or lesser than $(f(x'),g(x'),h(x'))$ ?

Comment: In fact, each function has the different variable, it should be $\min(f(x_1),g(x_2),h(x_3))$. How to write the correct notation to find the minimum of those functions? Let's say $x_1$ makes $f(x_1)$ is lower than $g(x_2)$ and $h(x_3)$

Comment: Well $\min_{x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)} \min(f(x_1),g(x_2),h(x_3))$ would be the same as $\min (\min_x f(x), \min_x g(x), \min_x h(x))$.